# What Happened to --report-useless-tests in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm working on upgrading a test suite/harness written against PHPUnit 5 to PHPUnit 7.  The harness uses PHPUnit's `--report-useless-tests` command line option/flag.  However, this option/flag is gone in PHPUnit 6 and PHPUnit 7.

What happened to this flag?  Was it replaced with another?  Or was it made redundant for -- reasons? (what are those reasons). Or some third thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've gathered the behavior of `--report-useless-tests` in PHPUnit 6+ is now the *default* reporting behavior.  Modern versions of PHPUnit have a `--dont-report-useless-tests` to restore the behavior of older versions of PHPUnit.